# Multistage Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to create a multistage pipeline is this any possibility that we can create multiple build for multiple environment. like for dev first build is run successfully then release and for QA first build is successfully deploy and then release in one yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can follow below sample/framework to set up your YAML pipeline.

Suppose you have two environments: **`Dev`** and **`QA`**. And you want to build any deploy in the **`Dev`** environment at first. If successful in **`Dev`**, then build any deploy in the **`QA`** environment.

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```yaml
. . .

stages:
- stage: Dev
  displayName: 'Dev env'
  . . .
  jobs:
  - job: build
    displayName: 'Build job'
    . . .

  - deployment: deploy
    displayName: 'Deploy job'
    dependsOn: build
    . . .

- stage: QA
  displayName: 'QA env'
  dependsOn: Dev
  . . .
  jobs:
  - job: build
    displayName: 'Build job'
    . . .
  
  - deployment: deploy
    displayName: 'Deploy job'
    dependsOn: build
    . . .
```

For more details, you can reference the document about "[**Add stages, dependencies, & conditions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".